# K8s RBAC authorization functionality

Tags: kubernetes, k8s-rolebinding

1. What is `rbac.authorization.k8s.io`? is that just the api version RBAC uses to work, etc
2. When you run a `RBAC` command (for example creating a role), is the request sent to the master server to process or is that done locally on the node? how is that process working?
3. What are API groups? when defining a role I notice it asks for this, what's it referring to? EX: `apiGroups: [""]`

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time, and make sure your questions are actually programming-related.  Is this in the context of, for example, a Go-based Kubernetes controller?  Or is it more a question about Kubernetes administration?

Answer (score 0):

1. The [rbac.authorization.k8s.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) is a type of authorization in kubernetes that sets access such as ["clusterRole" and "RoleBinding"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) for individual user access. This help admins to dynamically configure permissions in K8s API. There are other authorization modes that you can see here in the [official docs.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules)
2. It is typically sent to the control plane and evaluate users that shall access the cluster. This is easier to manage on a cloud provider since there are pre-existing APIs that are connected to authentication services of the provider.
3. API groups are used for modification purposes in "verb" type. You can use the following [request verbs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb) to create your RBAC mode authorization rules.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Comment: Empty "" means CORE API group, but what is the core API group? Is that `rbac.authorization.k8s.io`?

Comment: Core (legacy)  API groups are used to extend Kubernetes APIs. You can see full details about core/legacy APIs on this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.28/#api-groups)

Comment: So, if I have the following in the same YAML file for a Role, what's the difference between the two?
`apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` `apiGroups: - apps`